# Syntax to read xml inside of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am passing into `@xCriteria` a XML parameter that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchParameters xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <includeInactive enabled="True" />
</searchParameters>
```

I know the xpath is:  `//includeInactive/@enabled`

And have tried:

```
--determine if we include inactive users
DECLARE @isInactive AS bit

-- SELECT @isInactive = @xCriteria.value('(/includeInactive/@enabled', 'bit')
-- SET @isInactive = @xCriteria.query('/includeInactive/@enabled')
-- SELECT @isInactive.value('(/includeInactive/enabled)[1]', 'bit')
-- SELECT @isInactive = @xCriteria.query('/includeInactive/@enabled')  

PRINT '@isInactive'
PRINT @isInactive
```

How can I fetch the boolean value?

Comment: In Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try like this:

```
DECLARE @isInactive AS BIT;

SELECT
    @isInactive = CASE @param.value('(/searchParameters/includeInactive)[1]/@enabled', 'bit') 
                     WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1
                  END

SELECT @isInactive;
```

You basically need to select the first (`(....)[1]`) `<includeInactive>` node inside the root node, and then get the `@enabled` attribute off that node.

And you need to clunky `CASE` expression, since your XML stores the value of **enabled**, while the variable you want to get is the exact opposite - **@isInactive**.